# Trying to cross-build and package project with qemu and get a "Imported target "PkgConfig::gst" includes non-existent path" error

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, cross-compiling, qemu, arm64

I have a project that I'm trying to build on an arm64 architecture. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, so I use qemu to cross-build. I'm using the following instructions to emulate an arm64 environment :

```
sudo apt-get install debootstrap qemu-user-static schroot
sudo qemu-debootstrap --arch=arm64 bionic arm64-ubuntu

echo "[arm64-ubuntu]
description=Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial (arm64)
directory=$(pwd)/arm64-ubuntu
root-users=$(whoami)
users=$(whoami)
type=directory" | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/arm64-ubuntu

schroot -c arm64-ubuntu -u root
```

It works, and when I'm in the emulated environment I can then install all I need with the following commands :

```
add-apt-repository universe
add-apt-repository "deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main universe"
apt update && apt full-upgrade

sudo apt install cmake pkg-config libglib2.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstrtspserver-1.0-dev
```

Again, it works and everything seems to install normally. But then when I run :

```
cmake ..
```

I get the following error :

```
(arm64-ubuntu)root@me-mypc:/home/me/Projets/embedded/vespa/build# cmake ..
-- Configuring done
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "PkgConfig::gst" includes non-existent path

    "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.



CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "PkgConfig::gst" includes non-existent path

    "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.



-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/Projets/embedded/vespa/build
```

As the files have been built anyway I can still try to make the package :

```
make package
```

But the I get an error saying :

```
(arm64-ubuntu)root@me-mypc-5590:/home/me/Projets/embedded/vespa/build# make package
Scanning dependencies of target vespa
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/vespa.dir/src/main.c.o
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /home/path_to_project/src/main.c:3:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32:10: fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glibconfig.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/vespa.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/vespa.dir/src/main.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vespa.dir/src/main.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/vespa.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vespa.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Unless I'm wrong, it would seem that the cmake error prevents the project to build correctly. So I think the error comes from there. And indeed when I try to check if the glib2.0 lib has been correctly installed, I can see that there is no /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ directory. I don't understand why this directory isn't automatically created with the emulated environment. I tried to create it by installing gcc manually but even then the dependancies aren't installed in it. I  even tried to copy manually all the required dependancies, and it partially worked, as the cmake command succeeded, but the make command failed, saying it lacked libraries that were installed.

Here is the CMakeLists I'm using :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(
    vespa 
    VERSION 0.2.0
    LANGUAGES C
)

find_package(PkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(
    gst REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
    gstreamer-1.0
    gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0
    gstreamer-rtsp-1.0
)

pkg_check_modules(
    glib REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
    glib-2.0
)

add_executable(
    vespa
    src/main.c
)

target_link_libraries(
    vespa
    PUBLIC
    m
    PkgConfig::gst
    PkgConfig::glib
)

install(
    TARGETS vespa
    DESTINATION bin
)

set_property(TARGET vespa PROPERTY VERSION ${vespa_VERSION})
set_property(TARGET vespa PROPERTY SOVERSION ${vespa_VERSION_MAJOR})

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH})
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_FILE_NAME DEB-DEFAULT)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libgstrtspserver-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0-1)")
include(CPack)
```

I know the error doesn't come from the files I use, or from the commands I'm using, as it worked for everyone else who tried it.

I don't understand what makes it fail on my pc.

************** EDIT ***************

The comments from Tarmo (thank you) made me look in another direction and I think I understand the problem better.

As I said, when trying to run :

```
cmake ..
```

CMake tells me it tries to find "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include". Which doesn't exist, because in this emulated arm64 environment, an x86_64 path doesn't exist.

So I tried to locate the glib using :

```
pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
```

And it returned :

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

Which seems logic to me, in an arm64 environment.

So it would seem pkg-config locates glib correctly in cmd line, but not when used in the CMakeLists. I don't understand why.

Comment: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include` is an x86 component. Why is your arm64 build trying to access x86 includes? Perhaps you need to tell your cmake project to target arm64?

Comment: @Tarmo I'm not the one who created it, I'm only using it. I edited the message with the CMakeLists file used by CMake. But I shouldn't modify it, as it worked fine for everyone else who used it.

Comment: Are you quite sure you've set up the arm64 emulation environment correctly and are in it when executing cmake? cmake seems to be thinking it's in an x86 environment.

Comment: @Tarmo I'm sure I'm in it, yes. As for the validity of the setup, no, I'm not sure. All the commands I used for it are in the post, they worked for other people but I'm not experimented enough with these technologies to know where there can be an error.